# htaccess redirect from old url to new friendly url not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

i've working on a ecommerce website, and on the landing page there are several products which user can see, if a user wants to see more details about a particular product he has to click on it which will then take him to viewproduct.php?productname=fidget-spinner&code=12345&id=12345

what i want is when a user clicks on a product URL should be this : viewproduct.php/productname/fidgetspinner/code/12345/id/12345

I am able to create a seo friendly url using htaccess but i have to go to viewproduct.php?productname=fidget-spinner&code=12345&id=12345
 and then manually in the url i have to type the friendly url which works fine..i want seo friendly user to be displayed when a user clicks on viewproduct.php

any new suggestions would be appreciated!!

NEW FRIENDLY SEO URL :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule www.example.com/productname/(.*)/code/(.*)/id/(.*)$ viewproduct.php?productname=$1&code=$2&id=$3
```

this is what i've tried until now to redirect to new url when a user clicks on a product :

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^www.example.com/productname/([a-z0-9]+)/code/([0-9]+)/id/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ viewproduct.php?productname=$1&code=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: Why are you including `www.example.com/`? That is not required.

Comment: @MikeRockett thanks for the help..i tried removing that too..still doesn't work ..this is how my htaccess file looks like after making the changes as you mentioned

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^productname/([a-z0-9]+)/code/([0-9]+)/id/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ viewproduct.php?productname=$1&code=$2&id=$3

Comment: Hold on, your actualy problem is that the friendly link is not being displayed? Is the actual link working? So if you go to `productname/...`, does it show what it's supposed to show?

Comment: no brother it says 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//Redirect old file path to new file path//

Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Comment: appreciate your help!! but not working..does it work for you?